# Extracting Installer Data

Tags: archiving, installer, extract

I have a game. It has these files

1. Setup-1.bin
2. Setup-2.bin
3. Setup-3.bin
4. Setup-4.bin
5. Setup.exe

When I install, it extracts it in `C:`. Now the game is quite bigger, free space on `C:` seems always insufficient. I have `6GB` space. Still it says low space. So I was thinking to extract it to some other driver and install from there.  Now these files are not regular archives (zip, rar, gzip etc). So an archive utility like `7zip` fails to extract. The pattern of these files tell me it came from a Installer software (installshield etc). If I can find which software is used to create it I might be able to extract it.

Could you tell which software would be able to extract this installer archive?

Comment: @Shiptu 'winzip' is capable to extract .bin files,select your '.bin' file goto properties select 'open with' choose 'winzip';

Comment: @vignesh its neither zip file nor using zip compression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) works with InstallShield installers and other types of installers. If that doesn't work, could you link to the installer file? Then we could better determine what kind of archive it is.

Comment: [This](http://blackboxrepack.com/max-payne-3-black-box/) is the game I am talking about. Its size is originally 28Gb. But this installer made it 10GB. Still it need huge space in c drive

Comment: it detected, `Signature detected: Inno Setup Setup Data (5.4.2)` but failed to extract

Comment: wow, I don't have enough space or bandwidth to spend downloading another 10 GB file, sorry, but if it failed to extract, then maybe the download is corrupted? It happens a lot, especially when downloading with IE or Chrome. Try finding an MD5 hash for it, or redownloading in Firefox. Or you could try http://innounp.sourceforge.net/ which is made specially for Inno Setup files, and will probably give you a more accurate error message.

Comment: I free up space on C drive and installed it :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use Inno extract. Usually installers in the format "Setup-1.bin" would work with it.

For simplicity's sake you could drag and drop the setup.exe on top of innoextract.exe and it'll automatically extract into a folder named "app".

https://github.com/dscharrer/innoextract/releases